# Angular 5 HTML not updating after variable change

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm having a strange issue where my HTML page isn't updating when the angular component variable changes.  After pressing a button I do a network load and start playing audio like so:

```js
onPreviewPressed(media: Media): void {
    if (this.playing) {
        this.playing = false;
        this.source.stop();
    }

    this.loading = true;

    this.service.downloadAudio(this.gender, this.style, this.ageRange, media).subscribe(abuf => {
        this.context.decodeAudioData(abuf, buffer => {
            this.source.buffer = buffer;
            this.playing = true;
            console.info(`Playing is ${this.playing}`);
            this.source.start(0);
        }, y => {
            console.info('Error: ' + y);
        });
        this.loading = false;
    }, () => {
        this.loading = false;
    });
}
```

And then on my HTML I have this snippet:

```
Playing is {{ playing }}
<button [hidden]="!playing" style="width: 44px; height: 44px" (click)="onStopPressed()">
    <img src="/assets/stop.png" alt="Stop">
</button>
```

When I click the button the audio properly downloads and starts playing, and in the console I see it say `Playing is true` but the HTML continues to say false, and doesn't show the button.

I thought it might be an issue of `this` not really being the component but the window variable, but if that were the case then the audio would really be able to play either as the `source` variable is part of the component.

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `onPreviewPressed`?

Comment: using hidden is actually not recommended http://blog.angularjs.org/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Possible cause

It looks like the `playing` is not being capture as a part of change detector mechanism in Angular.

### Fix : You have a couple of choices

> The first is to use setters and getters for the `playing` variable

Functions always play a vital role as part of change detector so it ensures that your change in variable reflects.

### In *.ts

```
get playingValue(){
    return this.playing;
}

set playingValue(playing){
    this.playing = playing;
}
```

### In *.html

```
Playing is {{ playingValue }}
```

> The second option is to use setTimeout(...)

```
this.service.downloadAudio(this.gender, this.style, this.ageRange, media).subscribe(abuf => {
        this.context.decodeAudioData(abuf, buffer => {
            this.source.buffer = buffer;

            setTimeout(()=>this.playing = true);  //setTimeout
            
            console.info(`Playing is ${this.playing}`);
            this.source.start(0);
        }, y => {
            console.info('Error: ' + y);
        });
        this.loading = false;
    }, () => {
        this.loading = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by:

```
#Inject ChangeDetectorRef to the constructor
 constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef)

ngOnInit(): void {
  # get data or listen to changes
  # then 
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Remember to import it by:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thanks! It can happen when the variable is updated inside an event listener. It'll be outside the Angular change detector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<button *ngIf="playing" style="width: 44px; height: 44px" (click)="onStopPressed()">
    <img src="/assets/stop.png" alt="Stop">
</button>
```