# How to detect outside clicks in ionic native APPs?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, onclick, angular12

I created a boolean `isStationSelected` to know if the element is selected or not.

In which case I show a select button. The problem is that the value never updates.

I have tried plenty of solution, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907589/7942242) or [this article](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-2-not-reflecting-change-in-variable-and-model-value-passed-in-component-method-as-parameter-argument-resolved/) and many others, but none of theme worked.

I have tried some other solutions found on internet but no success, the value stay to the initial state.

html

```
<div>
    <div #station> 
        {{isStationSelected}} // always false
    </div>
    <button
      [ngClass]="{'hidden': !isStationSelected, 'block': isStationSelected}">
        Select
    </button>
</div>
```

ts

```
  ...
  @ViewChild('station') station: ElementRef;

  public isStationSelected: boolean = false

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.renderer.listen('window', 'click', (e: Event) => {
      this.station.nativeElement.contains(e.target) ?
        this.isStationSelected = true :
        this.isStationSelected = false
    })
  }
...
```

I reproduced exactly what I have https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-cljwhp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

But I do not get the problem in stackblitz... I think this is beceause ionic on a device. But how to fix it, or to detect outside clicks ?

I also tried to use a toggle function

```
  toggle() {
    this.isStationSelected = !this.isStationSelected
    console.log("fired");
  }
```

Which works nice **when it is not in an event listener** like  `this.renderer.listen('window', 'click')` or     `document.addEventListener("click")` for exemple.

(If I use the `toggle()` function in a `button` on click it works fine)

The logs are always good, I mean `this.isStationSelected` as the value it should in the console, and the log `fired` is well displayed.

But the value does not change in front.

Comment: Seems to be working fine when clicking on the text, it shows the button: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkr7wr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I use angular ionic, I will look more into that, I guess ionic has something to do with that

Comment: I cannot manage to reproduce it in stackblitz, I will try in multiple devices

Comment: It's been a really good while since I've worked with ionic. But if you are trying on device, most likely click event is not happening like it will in browser. So my suggestion is to looking into that. Probably need to capture some other event than click. But first to diagnose issue, set a console log inside that listener, run it on device and check the dev console if it actually fires

Comment: I inspected it in the safari debugger, and it words, logs are well logged.. With the right value...

Comment: So have you tested it works on device, it is fired on device and console logging values?

Comment: The device do not change the value in the HTML, but in the device console (safari) it works fine.

Comment: I tested it on my iPhone 8 and it worked just fine. Just had to add a padding to the label so I won't touch the address bar. 
Are you sure that the issue is not caused by handling the event outside the Angular zone? This would exactly prevent a repaint while printing the characters in the console.
See here: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-3-renderer2-listen-14c6fe052b59

Answer (score 0):

## How to detect outside clicks in ionic native APPs ?

I wrap a `(click)` event on the `ion-content` and the `ion-header` to detect all clicks and execute `unselect()`.

```
  unselect(e) {
    if (this.button.nativeElement.contains(e.target)) return
    this.isSelected = false
  }
```

On my button I simple execute my toggle function

```
  toggleSelect() {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
  }
```